# Python BeautifulSOUP find text in html

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, google-search

I am trying to do google searcher by keyword and go through all the results and find if they have an text in like `"</div>"` `"<!DOCTYPE>"` or anything else, it's getting the html but my if always says div does not exist in any site.

Code :

```
from google import google
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def google_scrape(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soup.html

i = 1
query = 'תקליטן'
for url in google.search(query, 10):
    print("Trying : %s" % (url.link))
    try :
        html = google_scrape(url.link)
        if "</div>" in html:
            print("He have it")
        else:
            print("He doesnt have it")
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    #print(url.link)
```

Response:

```
Trying : https://www.youtube.com/?hl=iw&gl=IL    
He doesnt have it    
Trying : None
```

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout'

```
Trying : https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91    
He doesnt have it    
Trying : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube    
He doesnt have it    
Trying : https://www.facebook.com/youtube/
```

Comment: what is inside your `html` variable? You might have to first search for a block of code/ class inside your `google_search`  as in `html = soup.find_all(class_='CLASS_NAME_INSIDE_HTML')` and then just `return html` not `soup.html`

Comment: @mrbTT Its printing the view source of the page and I want to check if have in the source a string